# How to cache firebase storage pictures for PWA on firebase hosting

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, firebase-hosting

The idea is to allow registered users to upload their own profile picture and use efficient caching for the profile pictures valid across all visitors (not only registered ones).

I have PWA that is hosted outside google cloud but manages its users via firebase and stores pictures with firebase-storage. It seems a good idea to also use firebase-hosting on a custom subdomain which is to be used as a proxy/access manager etc for the access to firebase-storage (which in turn can be additionally cached via Cloudflare - optional).

Basically, we find ourselves with (private hosting: on the main domain) and (firebase hosting: on a subdomain). How could we manage who is logged in on the main app to the subdomain without passing metadata that would affect the caching we seek to obtain from the subdomain?

*At this stage,* **I hardly know how firebase manages its sessions**.
Any ideas suggestions are greatly appreciated!

The PWA is informed about the user logging in/out via JS events:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        //user is logged in
    } else {
        //user is logged out
    }
}
```

I checked a bunch of questions here like:
[Cache images received from Firebase Storage in PWA application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55055133/cache-images-received-from-firebase-storage-in-pwa-application)
[Set cache to files in Firebase Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44124537/set-cache-to-files-in-firebase-storage)
[Firebase storage downloadURL file structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114915/firebase-storage-downloadurl-file-structure)
[How to cache Firebase storage downloaded images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54234883/how-to-cache-firebase-storage-downloaded-images)

To upload a picture (from the private hosting) on firebase-storage using JS we can use:

```
<progress value="0" max="100" id="uploader">0%</progress><br />
<input type="file" id="photo" />
<script>
var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
var fileButton = document.getElementById('photo');
fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var ref = firebase.storage().ref();
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var name = (user.uid+'/1');
    var metadata = {
        'contentType': file.type,
        'cacheControl': 'private, max-age=15552000'
    };
    var task = ref.child(name).put(file, metadata);
    task.on('state_changed', 
        function progress(snapshot) {
            var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            uploader.value = percentage;
        },
        function error(err) {
            console.log(err);
        },
        function complete() {
            console.log('all done');
        }
    );
    task
    .then(snapshot => snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL())
    .then((url) => {
        console.log(url); //this "url" is to be saved on the profile for the authenticated user and used from within the firebase hosting
    })
    .catch(console.error);
});
</script>
```

Basically, when the picture is saved on firebase-storage we can save the "url" for the user profile. We want to use firebase-hosting to process the saving to firebase-storage (as it will be great to add cropping and other image manipulations prior saving to firebase storage, hence I believe that we need to be able to share session data). Once an image is saved on the firebase-storage I would like to implement caching via firebase-hosting.